# Capture non-adjacent repeating letters

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I capture repeating letters in a word like **abababa** = 2matches( **a** and **b** is repeating )

I know how to do it when the letters are adjacent like so **/(\w)\1+/** .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this *String* expansion:

```
String.prototype.getRepeating = function() {
  var length = this.length;
  var found = '';
  var repeating = '';
  var index;
  var letter;
  for (index = 0; index < length; index++) {
    letter = this.charAt(index);
    if (-1 == found.indexOf(letter)) {
      found = found.concat(letter);
    } else {
      if (-1 == repeating.indexOf(letter)) {
        repeating = repeating.concat(letter);
      }
    }
  }
  return repeating;
}
```

The tests:

```
var tests = ['ab', 'aa', 'bb', 'abab', 'abb', 'aab', 'bab'];
for (var index in tests) {
  console.log(tests[index], '=>', tests[index].getRepeating());
}
```

- ab => (an empty string)
- aa => a
- bb => b
- abab => ab
- abb => b
- aab => a
- bab => b

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to extract letters which appear more than once in a given word. If so, you simply need to iterate over the letters of the word, accumulate their occurrence, then filter out letters which only appear once.

```js
var testString = "abababa";
var letters = countGroupByLetter(testString);
var result = filterMap(letters, function(v) {
  return v > 1;
});
console.log(result);

function countGroupByLetter(testString) {
  var result = {};
  for (var ii = 0; ii < testString.length; ii++) {
    var letter = testString.charAt(ii);
    if (result[letter]) {
      result[letter] ++;
    } else {
      result[letter] = 1;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function filterMap(map, filterFunction) {
  var result = {};
  for (var p in map) {
    if (filterFunction(map[p])) {
      result[p] = map[p];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Since you already know about back references, I suppose that you know you can find out if there is a letter repetition in a string, using `/(\w).*\1/`. Capturing all repetitions in one pass would not be possible though, you'd still need to execute a pattern repeatedly and accumulate the matched characters (for instance using `/(\w)(?=.*\1)/g`). That, however, would not be optimal.

```js
var repeatingLetters = /(\w)(?=.*\1)/g;
var testString = "abababa";
var captures = null;
var result = {};
while ((captures = repeatingLetters.exec(testString)) != null) {
  result[captures[1]] = true;
}
console.log(result);
```